# Multiply price and quantity in custom listview in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I am fetching an array which displays itemimage, itemname, price, qty in a custom listview. Now I am placing one more field, total, which is calculated by multiplying price and quantity.

I am using this code:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
  {
    integer[] a;
public static ArrayList<String> arr1=new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> itemprice=new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<Bitmap> itemimage=new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
public Context Context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
String total;
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> arr,ArrayList<String> price,ArrayList<Bitmap> image) 
    {
        Context=context;
        inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        arr1=arr;
        itemprice=price;
        itemimage=image;
        System.out.println(itemprice);
        System.out.println("arr: " + arr.size());

      for(int i=0;i<price.size();i++)
      {

          String amonut=price.get(i);
          int x=Integer.parseInt(amonut);

      }

    }
    public int getCount() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arr1.size();

    }

    public Object getItem(int position) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arr1.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
        System.out.println(arr1.get(position));

          final  ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) 
            {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selecteditemlistview, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.textViewSelectedText = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.selectedtext);
                holder.price=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.selectitemprice);
                holder.image=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.selectitemimagge);
                holder.qty=(EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.selectqty);
                holder.total=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.totalamount);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else 
            {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            String amount=holder.qty.getText().toString();

            holder.textViewSelectedText.setText(arr1.get(position));
            holder.price.setText(itemprice.get(position));
            holder.image.setImageBitmap(itemimage.get(position));

            return convertView;     
        }

        class ViewHolder
        {
            TextView textViewSelectedText = null;
            TextView price=null;
            ImageView image=null;
            EditText qty=null;
            TextView total=null;
        }      
 }
```

I want to multiply int x and String amount and assign the result as text to total.

Comment: try using `Integer.parse(stringValue)` for the calculations.
p.s. not all of us are sirs, there are also some miss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ans = x * Integer.parseInt(amount); or

ans = x * Double.parseDouble(amount);

total = String.valueOf(ans);
```

Comment: try this holder.total.setText(total.toString());

Comment: i want multiply all prices * quantity i set default as 1 total automatically show as textview

Answer (score 0):

Change variable type according your requirement :-

```
    private float getTotal(String quantity, String price )
    {
    float total = 0f;

    try{
    float quant = Float.parseFloat(quantity);
    float unitCost= Float.parseFloat(price);

    total = unitCost*quant;


    }catch (Exception e) {

    }

    return total;
    }
```